# How to draw dynamic chart using jHipster?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jhipster

I wrote the application which gathers data from the server each minute. All gathered data is storage in PostgreSQL database.

How to create charts which display data in dynamic changing charts?

Is it possible to create simple SQL statements to the database and gather data?

Is a good idea to use angular nvd3?

Answer (score 1):

There are many charting libraries that can be used with Angular and JHipster. I'm personally using [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) with my JHipster application, and it's working great.

If your charts need to be updated in real time, JHipster provides Websockets support. The main issue with libraries using underneath [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) (like PrimeNG), is that it doesn't support live update of the graph: you need to tell PrimeNG to reload the whole graph. As this is only on the client side, it doesn't do much harm, and for most end-users they will just see their graph updated on-the-fly.

Comment: Is there any Quickstart guide or tutorial for using visualization tools like PrimeNG and Chart.js with Jhipster?